# Good bound for the function $h(x)=\frac{\sin(a\pi x)\sin(\pi x)}{\sin(b\pi x)\sin(c\pi x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider the function $h\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
h(x)=\frac{\sin(a\pi x)\sin(\pi x)}{\sin(b\pi x)\sin(c\pi x)},
$$
where $a,b,c$ are positive integers such that $a=bc$ with $(b,c)=1$. It is possible to show that this function is continuous by computing the limit at $x=n/b$ and $x=n/c$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $h$ attaches its maximum and minimum on $[0,1]$. I'm interested in finding a good upper bound for $|h(x)|$. Of course one upper bound is
$$
|h(x)|\leq \frac{1}{4\|bx\|\|cx\|},
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the distance to the nearest integer, but I would like a bound only on terms of $a,b,c$. For example, for $a=6$, $b=2$, $c=3$, we have $|h(x)|\leq 6$. I don't know if differentiating is a good option, because it's difficult to solve $h'(x)=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll write
$$
 h(x)=\frac{\sin(b c x)\sin( x)}{\sin(b x)\sin(c x)}
$$
for $0 \le x \le \pi$ to shorten the notation a bit.

For $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ and $n \in \Bbb Z$ is $|\sin(n \alpha)| \le |n| \cdot |\sin(\alpha)|$, which will be used several times in the following calculation.

$\gcd(b, c) = 1$ implies that there are integers $u, v$ with $1=ub + vc$ and $u, v$ can be chosen such that $|u| \le c$ and $|v| \le b$, see “structure of solutions” in [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Then
$$
 \sin(x) = \sin(ubx + vcx) = \sin(ubx) \cos(vcx) + \cos(ubx) \sin(vcx)
$$
and therefore
$$
|\sin(x)| \le |\sin(ubx)| + |\sin(vcx)| \le |u| |\sin(bx)| + |v| |\sin(cx)| \, .
$$

If $c|\sin(bx)| \le b|\sin(cx)|$ then
$$
|\sin(x)| \le \left(\frac bc |u|+|v|\right)|\sin(cx)|
$$
and therefore
$$
 |h(x)| \le c \frac{|\sin(x)|}{|\sin(cx)|} \le b|u| + c |v| \, .
$$
Similarly, if $c|\sin(bx)| \ge b|\sin(cx)|$ then
$$
|\sin(x)| \le \left(|u|+\frac cb |v|\right)|\sin(bx)|
$$
and
$$
 |h(x)| \le b \frac{|\sin(x)|}{|\sin(bx)|} \le b|u| + c |v|
$$
holds as well.

So in any case we have
$$
 \boxed{|h(x)| \le b|u| + c |v|  \le 2a\, .}
$$
This is surely not the best upper bound, but it depends only on $b$ and $c$, and not on $x$.

*Example:* $b=5$ and $c=7$. Then $1 = 3 \cdot 5 - 2 \cdot 7$ so that $u=3$ and $v= -2$. This gives an upper bound of $5\cdot 3 + 7 \cdot 2 = 29$ for $|h(x)|$. Plotting the functions shows that the actual upper bound is somewhere around $14$.

[image]